# How do I build my own Android project into an artifact?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, artifacts

I'm currently starting up in android dev. I have a dozen of non-sharing independent modules/folders which I'd be using in my main App Folder. Now for gradle to compile my project takes upto more than 3-5 minutes.

With some help from the web, I learnt that if by some means I can precompile my independent modules/folder into artifacts I could add them as dependancies (like adding precompiled Glide or ButterKnife dependancies) in build.gradle and circumvent recompiling again.

Now, How do I build artifacts of my own Android projects to be able to use it in build.gradle dependancies list?